# How to set Total Price with a quantity option list using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to adjust the total price dynamically when a quantity from 1-5 is selected. I am new to using Jquery so any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="quantity">
                    <option data-quantity="1">1</option>
                    <option data-quantity="2">2</option>
                    <option data-quantity="3">3</option>
                    <option data-quantity="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="price" data-price="@i.Price">$@i.Price</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>Total Price: $<span id="total></span></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var p = $("#price").find("[data-price]")

        $("#quantity").change(function () {
            var q = $(this).find(':selected').data('quantity');
            var total = p * q;
            $("#total").text(total);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `var p = Number($("#price").data('price'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already find the element with id `price`, so just get the `data-price` of it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const p = $("#price").data('price');

    $("#quantity").change(function () {
        const q = $(this).find(':selected').data('quantity');
        const total = p * q;
        $("#total").text(total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="quantity">
                    <option data-quantity="1">1</option>
                    <option data-quantity="2">2</option>
                    <option data-quantity="3">3</option>
                    <option data-quantity="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="price" data-price="1000">1000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>Total Price: $<span id="total"></span></p>
```

Comment: Note `data()` should return number...also would be cast to number using `*` operator so parseInt not really needed

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with this line `var p = $("#price").find("[data-price]")`, You may need the quantity

**Change to**

```
var p = $("#price").data("price");
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#quantity").on('change',function () {
                $('#total').text($('#price').attr('data-price') * $(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="quantity">
                        <option data-quantity="1">1</option>
                        <option data-quantity="2">2</option>
                        <option data-quantity="3">3</option>
                        <option data-quantity="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="price" data-price="500">500 $</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p>Total Price: $<span id="total"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```